# How to cycle through the various units/buildings in a single control group?

Tags: starcraft-2

I usually assign all of my command centers to hotkey 4.  Let's say I have three Command Centers (CCs) hotkeyed.  Double tapping 4 would take me to the CC which I selected last when creating the hotkey assignment.  Are there any tricks/tips for quickly cycling through all CCs (i.e., centering the screen on the first CC, then the second CC, then the third CC)?

For example, right now, I am doing the following to change rally point for each CC (to a different location): press 4 to select all CCs, click on the first CC in the green wire-mesh list of selected units, do the hotkey for centering screen on selected unit (Ctrl+F in my setup), right click to assign rally point, then repeat for all CCs.  I figured there is probably a more efficient way.

Or do folks simply assign each CC to a different hotkey?  (I currently assign to just one hotkey because I'm already using six other hotkey assignments).

I'm using CCs as an example - it would be helpful to understand how to do this for any given group of units/buildings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, double tapping 4 will actually take you to the closest CC to your current camera, not the last CC added to control group.

Now, to do what you want, you have a few options.

- Use the base location hotkey to jump to various CC's (This might actually be the best option for you.)
- Use camera hotkeys. You can assign f1 to your main, f2 to your nat, etc.
- Finally, some pros do this. have 4 be all your CC's, but then have 5-9 be your individual bases.  This way you can easy access mules/scans, but also jump to specific bases.

Now, the tab technique only works if you have multiple unit types, such as on 1 you might have marines and marauders, hitting tab changes from one to the other.  It will not allow you to select different CC's in your group, nor is there any easy way of doing that.

gl hf!

Comment: this is excellent, tyvm

Comment: IIRC the "base location" hotkey is bound to something sort of silly by default, but I've rebound it to `\``, which makes doing larvae injects a breeze. :)

Comment: @AlexisKing yeah, I rebound mine to q for the same purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah if I remember correctly you cycle with Tab, unless I didn't understand your question.

Comment: This might be better as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Backspace</kbd> will center on your base and cycle through them if you have more than one. Though, it's generally more useful to use camera hotkeys. They can be set using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5-F8</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F5-F8</kbd>. In order to recall the saved camera position, use <kbd>F#</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F#</kbd> respectively depending on which hotkey you used. For example,

- I set my main base to <kbd>F5</kbd>, and my production buildings to <kbd>F6</kbd>
- I set my expansions to <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F#</kbd>

I don't recommend setting all your production facilities to one hotkey. You can potentially save control groups by using a camera hotkey, and then selecting the buildings manually. Though, you generally want to keep your buildings hotkeyed.

Camera hotkeys are more useful because using a control group will select the building, which deselects anything you have selected. So if you want to move workers to your natural, you'd probably end up scrolling the edge of the screen. The camera hotkey allows you to quickly view another location to send your workers while having them still selected.

Comment: Interesting, so you use one control group hotkey for your barracks/factories/starports (or their equivalent) and you tab to jump between types?  I'm going to try that out.  Right now, I'm assigning one hotkey for barracks, a different hotkey for factories, etc.  But it might be inefficient.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @DipakC You could do that, but I wouldn't recommend it. I assign barracks to 3, factory to 4, and starport to 0.

Comment: Oh I see, I misunderstood.  Is it helpful to have redundancy in camera hotkeys and control-group hotkeys?  In other words - in the set up you described above, isn't F5 equivalent to double-tapping 3 (or 4 or 0, assuming they are all located near each other).  Lmk if I'm still misunderstanding...

Comment: @DipakC It's not equivalent. With a control group, it'll select the building, meaning if you want to move your units to another area without scrolling the screen, you can't (because it'll deselect your units). As I stated, this is useful when you want to transfer your workers painlessly. Camera hotkeys can also be used for strategic positions, like your enemy base or areas where no building is present (like a staging area for your army.)